# How to implement POST requset with complex data in retrofit 2

Tags: android, post, retrofit2

I am trying to implement in the android application with using Retrofit 2 the following curl request (example):

```html
POST  https://176.67.241.133/server/rest/v1/bulletins
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"    
--data "access_token=4cad3a733af72e4daf6550c7ace1a3886637747a&data[passport]=2212696912&data[bulletins][0][bulletin_id]=1&data[bulletins][0][value]=122222222&data[bulletins][1][bulletin_id]=2&data[bulletins][1][value]=222222222"
```

It can be performed in the js by the following code:

```js
$.post('/server/rest/v1/bulletins',
   {
       access_token: '83126ef617d83ee8843f8d49d94ab59bd349cf6d',
       data: {
           passport: '2212696911',
           bulletins: [
               {bulletin_id: 1, value: '122222222'},
               {bulletin_id: 2, value: '222222222'}
           ]
       }
   },
   function (result) {
       $('#bulletin').html(JSON.stringify(result));
   });
```

I have try the code below where Voting is json model with apropriate data structure, but it is converted to wrong request.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/server/rest/v1/bulletins")
Observable<Object> postBulletins(@Field("access_token") String accessToken, @Field("data") Voting votingData);
```

Could you please help with writing correct request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the @Field annotation is supposed to be used with a String objects. You should probably turn your data to be posted into a pojo and using the @Body annotation to post it. I use http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/ to generate quick pojo's. After you create your object you can post it using

```
    @POST("/server/rest/v1/bulletins")
    Observable<Object> postBulletins(@Body YourPojoClassName 
    yourPojoClass);
```

Your pojo will look something like this:

```
    public class YourPojoClassName{

        String access_token;
        Data data;

        public static class Data{

            int passport;
            Bulletins[] bulletins;

            public static class Bulletins{
                int bulletin_id;
                int value;
            }
        }
    }
```